# The nearest 10am in the future?

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way to use `strtotime` to get the next, say, 10am in the future? If it's 9:59am, the next 10am is today. If it's 10:00am, the next 10am is tomorrow. `strtotime('next 10am')` doesn't work.

Solution doesn't need to use `strototime`. Suggestions?

Comment: You're almost at 10K... time for a new username :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple if will do the trick

```
$time = time() < strtotime('10:00am')
   ? strtotime('10:00am')
   : strtotime('tomorrow 10:00am');
```

In words: If the *current time* is before *10am today* than the time is *10am today* otherwise the time is *10am tomorrow*.

Comment: I think I'm getting the previous 10am. Checking still.

Comment: Is it supposed to be `time() >` ?

Comment: And should it be `strtotime('today 10:00am')`?

Comment: It's 5pm where I am. Running the code gives me 10am this morning, instead of 10am tomorrow.

Comment: The solution is correct, it shouldn't be `>`, that would state the current time is after 10am today. And `strtotime('today 10:00am') === strtotime('10:00am')`.

Comment: Remember time zones guys ;)

Comment: OK - how do I specify timezone?

Comment: The timezone that is configured for PHP might differ from your location. Run `echo date('Y-m-d h:i:sA');` to see the current time. The timezone is configured in php.ini as [`date.timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't include editing `php.ini`?

Comment: You can set it at runtime with `ini_set('date.timezone', "Europe/Amsterdam")`. How to deal with timezones in PHP is really a different question all together though. If you continue to struggle with it, you should as a new question.